# $scope.$watch works just at deleting category form treeview in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, treeview, watch

I have a simple application with *treeview of categories and phones* at page:

```
<div id="treeView">
            <div dx-tree-view="treeViewOptions"></div>
</div>
```

[image]

I wrote the *watch* function in my controller:

```
$scope.$watch('treeViewOptions', function () {
        console.log("TreeView was changed");
    });
```

But message in console displays just after i deleting category(ies) 
May be somebody knows how i can check all changes in my *treeview*?
Thanks for your answers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should set objectEquality to "true"

`$scope.$watch('treeViewOptions', function () {
        console.log("TreeView was changed");
    }, true);`

From https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope

> $watch(watchExpression, listener, [objectEquality]);
>
> When objectEquality == true, inequality of the watchExpression is determined according to the angular.equals function. To save the value of the object for later comparison, the angular.copy function is used. This therefore means that watching complex objects will have adverse memory and performance implications.